# Remove icon from searchview in ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat

I am using action bar support v7 library. When I expand search view I get look like this.

[image]

**I dont want this search icon on left.** Instead I want to place it in hint like image below.

[image]

I want to do this programmatically. How can I achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: If you add a hint, what happens? I seem to recall having a hint and maybe using `setIconified()` (I forget if true or false) had some control over this...

Comment: If I add hint it shows hint but search icon remains on left. I have set mSearchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false); to keep it expanded by default.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think I figured out what the answer is.

To expand searchview by default if I use

```
mSearchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
```

it will show search bar like first image

If I use `mSearchView.onActionViewExpanded();` then it shows like second image.